# How to effectively find a value in a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, null, key

I am working with hashes that are in the following format:

```
{2013-09-19 11:37:18 UTC=>10.780000000000001, 2013-09-21 11:37:18 UTC=>2.55, 2013-09-23 08:42:25 UTC=>2.55}
```

Then I have a loop where I have date value in this format **2013-09-21**. I am trying to find a value in the hash according to the date value.

Here's what I am trying:

```
%div "#{@data1.select{|key, hash| key.strftime('yyyy-MM-dd').to_s == day.to_s }}"
%div "#{@data2.select{|key, hash| key.to_s == day.to_s }}"
```

But in both cases I am getting an empty array. One way is to loop through the whole hash and compare value, but this is probably not very effective way to find the item in the hash.

I am trying the `select` method above, but I am not sure how to use it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `day`is a `String`, try

```
@data1.select{|key, hash| key.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == day}
```

If `day` is a `Date` object, try

```
@data1.select{|key, hash| key.to_date == day}
```

To return the value of selected key do

```
@data1.select{|key, hash| key.to_date == day}.values.first
```

Comment: Great, it's working, thanks. But the output is in this format: `{2013-09-19 11:37:18 UTC=>10.780000000000001}`. How to print out only value?

Comment: @tihom, use `.values` at the end not `[1]` in case if select produced more then one key/value pair

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you compare DateTime to Date (given the formatting of both).

So, you may do something like that :

```
%div "#{@data1.select{|key, hash| key.to_date.to_s == day.to_s }}"
%div "#{@data2.select{|key, hash| key.to_date.to_s == day.to_s }}"
```